# Can I post answers or some code that I have created to stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

Lets say I just want to share with people and provide code, should I post code using the question method or is there some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is related to the actual site and not just a desire for a blog or something, the info you want to share should be put in a Q&A format.

But you can answer your own questions easily and actually immediately. There's a checkbox when you ask a question to immediately provide an answer to your own question at the same time the question shows up.

[image]

I always felt this is a weird thing to do (it looks like someone talking to himself), but I've seen some users utilize this to great effect. Here is one example: [What's the standard/official name for universal references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904462/whats-the-standard-official-name-for-universal-references)

This is a very useful question, likely on the mind of many C++ users, with an equally useful answer.

You should make sure you have something truly worthy to share. The question should be something a lot of people are wondering about, and the answer should really hit the spot. But if you have info to share which fits this format well then I'd suggest go ahead, answer your own question immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you create your own blog for that. You can easily create a Jekyll-based blog on GitHub nowadays which will also allow other developers to contribute back to you (e.g. via pull-requests). https://pages.github.com

Alternatively, you can use one of the many other great static site generators out there: http://www.staticgen.com